# Scope of for loop control variable in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a question about for loop in shell.

Let's assume this simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
loop() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    for i in 1 2 3 4; do                                                                                                                                           
        if [ $i -eq 2 ]; then                                                                                                                                      
            [ $1 -eq 2 ] && return 1                                                                                                                           
            loop $(($1 + 1)) && return 1                                                                                                                     
        fi                                                                                                                                                         
    done                                                                                                                                                           
return 1                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                  

loop 0
```

All variables are global, except for arguments (and function arguments). So if I want a local variable in function
I would have to pass it as argument.

I tried to run this simple script, but I'm not sure if also the for loop list (1 2 3 4 in this example) is also local? 
See below:

```
+ loop 0
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 1 -eq 2 ']'
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 2 -eq 2 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 2 ']'
+ loop 1
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 1 -eq 2 ']'
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 2 -eq 2 ']'
+ '[' 1 -eq 2 ']'
+ loop 2
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 1 -eq 2 ']'
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 2 -eq 2 ']'
+ '[' 2 -eq 2 ']'
+ return 1
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 3 -eq 2 ']'
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 4 -eq 2 ']'   <- here is $i == 4
+ return 1
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 3 -eq 2 ']'   <- here is $i == 3, correctly behaving as local variable ...
+ for i in 1 2 3 4
+ '[' 4 -eq 2 ']'
+ return 1
```

Can anyone please tell me, how the for loop works internally? I am bit confused about the for loop list, that is behaving like "local variable".

Thank you very much for all your answers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `for…in` statement has an implicit local state (which I wouldn't call a variable because it has no name and there is no way to inspect it). This local state consists of the unconsumed part of the fully evaluated list of words to iterate over.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the answer I was looking for :)

Also, isn't everything textual in shell? How should I understand as non-numerical (or numerical) for statement? Thank you!

Comment: @bomba: `for ((expr;expr;expr))` evaluates its arguments in a numeric context. The second and third expression are evaluated on every loop. But I changed the answer to make it less confusing what I mean (I hope).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much @rici ! :)

Answer (score 4):

Shells have no concepts of loop control variables. All variables are global unless their declared function-local, usually with the `local` keyword.

Some shells have dynamic scoping, which means a callee may access a local variable in its caller if it doesn't overshadow it with its own local variable.

In your example, all this is irrelevant, though. The `for` statements only write to the variable. They don't read it. When a `loop` returns, the caller's `for` continues where it left off.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't understand, why does the _i_ variable get set to the correct value (continuing the for loop). 

Does this mean, that the for loop does not evaluate the _i_ value, but only assigns the values from the list? If yes, where is the information of the last used value stored? Because if it was evaluating every time according to the _i_ value, what next value should be set then when it was once set to 4, it would not have been set back to 3, as it is doing (and it would slow).

Comment: @bomba: how do you suppose that the shell could use the *value* of `$i` to decide what the next loop value might be? (Does your theory work with `for i in 1 1 1 1; do echo $i: done`?)

Comment: @rici yes, it is not probably evaluating the `$i` value every time, I meant it more like a counter-example to the behaviour that we can see from the output. So then my question is, is there some hidden "pointer" to the last value used in the for loop? If this "hidden pointer" was uniqe to every for loop, then I guess that could explain this behaviour.